# Compare datagrid cell values c# application

Tags: c#

I'm doing one jewelry project using c# application.

I facing the problem in purchase form.

[image]

In that above picture, I want to check Jewel ID column and Purity column.

I wrote this code:

```
foreach (DataRow row in objDT.Rows)
{
    if (row[0].ToString() == localJewelID )
    {

       MessageBox.Show("Product Added Already!);

        txtJewelname.Focus();
        //cmbPayStructure.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

But if I add next jewel with the same Jewel Id with the purity 22ct that time also I got the same alert ie., "Product Added Already!"..

I want the solution like this:

```
JewelID  JewelName Purity

J0001    CHAIN       916
J0001    CHAIN       22CT
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify if the new Jewelry you're adding has the same Id and the same purity

```
foreach (DataRow row in objDT.Rows)
{
    if (row[0].ToString() == localJewelID && row[2].ToString() == localPurity)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Product Added Already!);

        txtJewelname.Focus();
        //cmbPayStructure.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }     
}
```

So here you compare the new Jewelry and only show the message if both the Id and the purity are the same.

Comment: Thank u friend.. but am not stored the value for 'localpurity'. The value available in datagridview only.. and the column index numbe is 2 ... can you give me the idea ???...